# When does MySQL rebuild a FTS index?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, query-performance

If you want to use the [MySQL Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) functionality you define a Full Text Index on field(s) with type VARCHAR. As rows are INSERTed and UPDATEd, mysql has to keep the indexes up-to-date. My question is: **When does MySQL rebuild a FTS index?**

- A) Immediately after a INSERT or UPDATE occurs that affects the index.
- B) When the first SELECT is run that needs the index which has recently been affected by  a UPDATE or INSERT.
- C) Something else.

---

*Unecessary background info*: My experience seems to think option B. Is this right? I ask because I have been experiencing sudden random slow queries which do a Full Text Search and I don't know why some are slow and not the others. My hunch is that the queries can be slow if they are waiting for mysql to rebuild the FTS index, but I don't know if this is how mysql works. Example of a random slow query (usually the same query runs under a second), there is no slow UPDATE or INSERT in the slow log:

```
# Query_time: 61.775612  Lock_time: 10.110924 Rows_sent: 20  Rows_examined: 222498
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id
FROM members
WHERE
    AND MATCH (bio,profile_text,name) AGAINST ('building surveyor')
    AND MATCH (town, postcode, country) AGAINST ('united kingdom, liverpool');
```

Notice the Lock_time. I can't see any other INSERT or UPDATE in the slow log, so I'm not sure what it is waiting for. That is why I guessed it could be waiting for a FTS index rebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `... AGAINST('"building surveyor"')` to get that phrase instead of those two words scattered anywhere.

Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?  They work differently.

MyISAM, I think, *updates* the FT indexes when a row is inserted/updated.

InnoDB, I think, queues up changes, and eventually writes them to disk.  This generally makes it faster for writes than MyISAM.

Neither Engine *rebuilds* the index except when explicitly asked to.